# data.table reference column in another data.table by name

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.tables:

```
Comparison <- data.table(code = c("AAA", "BBB"),
                         elem1 = c(1, 2),
                         elem2 = c(4, 4))

DT <- data.table(A = c("AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA"),
                 B = c("BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB"),
                 C = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Now, I would want to add a new column based on a comparison of a column from `Comparison` and from `DT`. The following command generates the expected output:

```
DT[, newCol := {ifelse( abs(C - Comparison[code == "AAA", elem2]) == 0, "0", "1")}]

Output:

     A   B C newCol
1: AAA BBB 1      1
2: AAA BBB 2      1
3: AAA BBB 3      1
4: AAA BBB 4      0
```

However, if instead of hardcoding the column value of the column `A`, I use the column itself with this:

```
DT[, newCol := {ifelse( abs(C - Comparison[code == A, elem2]) > 0, "0", "1")}]
```

It outputs the following error, which I'm not sure how to avoid:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(Comparison, code == A, elem2) : 
  RHS of == is length 4 which is not 1 or nrow (2). For robustness, no recycling is allowed (other than of length 1 RHS). Consider %in% instead.
```

It seems to me that the operation is not vectorizing the elements of the column `A` of `DT` in `Comparison` and I don't really understand why, because the elements of the column `C` are taken properly (i.e. it uses the elements of `C` individually but not the elements of `A`). How could I perform this comparison?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `join` with `on`

```
DT[Comparison, newCol := as.integer(C != elem2), on = c("A" = "code"), nomatch = 0]
DT
#     A   B C newCol
#1: AAA BBB 1      1
#2: AAA BBB 2      1
#3: AAA BBB 3      1
#4: AAA BBB 4      0
```

Comment: This is lovely and streamlined, but when I try it on my own data (similar situation to the OP) I get a warning: `> lab_results[elisaout, quantitativeResult := as.character(Valeur), on = c("sampleIdentifier" = "SID"), nomatch = 0]
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(lab_results, elisaout, `:=`(quantitativeResult,  :
  nomatch isn't relevant together with :=, ignoring nomatch`

Comment: @AmyM Can you post as a question with a small reproducible example with `dput` so that it becomes easier to check the structure etc.

Comment: it turns out that I can just remove `nomatch = 0` from this statement and it works fine.   In my case the first dt has e.g. 3 rows and the second dt has 4 rows.  I am filling the second dt with values from the first by reference to the same IDs.  I sorted them both on the same IDs before doing this and all the IDs in the first dt matched an ID in the second dt (though obviously not vice versa) so I guess that is why ` nomatch = 0` isn't relevant in this case?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to do the merge of data.

```
require(data.table)

Comparison <- data.table(code = c("AAA", "BBB"),
                         elem1 = c(1, 2),
                         elem2 = c(4, 4))
Comparison

DT <- data.table(A = c("AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA"),
                 B = c("BBB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB"),
                 C = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
DT

tmp <- merge(DT, Comparison, by.x = "A", by.y = "code")
tmp[, newCol := as.character(as.integer(C != elem2))]
tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read the error message it says `Consider %in% instead.`

Indeed by replacing `==` with `%in%` it works without having to use `join` or `merge`.

```
DT[, newCol := {ifelse( abs(C - Comparison[code %in% A, elem2]) = 0, "0", "1")}

DT

#     A   B C newCol
#1: AAA BBB 1      1
#2: AAA BBB 2      1
#3: AAA BBB 3      1
#4: AAA BBB 4      0
```